# Audio not working

Tags: javascript, audio

```
var audio = new Audio("https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=8E89450E6091B685&resid=8E89450E6091B685%21725&authkey=AMbCpgb-EbUhsVs");
audio.play;
```

This code does not play any sound, it only returns:

```
=> [Function: play]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=> [Function: play]
```

looks to be indicating the intended usage and that it expects a form like the one given by Chrome 54:

```
function play() { [native code] }
```

`audio.play()` returns a Promise. Currently in console, `[[PromiseStatus]]:"rejected"` due to `DOMException: The element has no supported sources`.

I suggest using a Promise to play the audio. Here is an example: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/play-return-promise/
and the post explaining the example: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/play-returns-promise

There is also this similar question: [How can i create a promise for the end of playing sound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069988/how-can-i-create-a-promise-for-the-end-of-playing-sound)