# How to find HTMLAudioElement audio ended playing

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

An application is playing an audio clip with the HTMLAudioElement in JavaScript like below,

```
mySound = new Audio([URLString]);
```

The URL string will keep on changing based on user clicks.

Any ways to find when HTMLAudioElement audio completed? I tried the "ended" property but the function is not being called after audio finished playing.

Comment: Is it not just `onended` like `mySound.onended = function(){ ... };`

Answer (score 6):

As @Djave notes in their comment, and as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30070516/3412775), you can use the `onended` event for Audio objects created with JS (as opposed to `ended`, which is valid if you're using DOM elements):

```
mySound = new Audio(audioFile);
mySound.onended = function() {
    // Whatever you want to do when the audio ends.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> any ways to find when HTMLAudioElement audio completed

You can use the `ended` Event Listener:

**HTML:**

```
<audio>
  <source src="/my-audio-clip.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var myAudioClip = document.querySelector('[src="/my-audio-clip.mp3"]');
myAudioClip.addEventListener('ended', myFunction, false);
```

---

**Further Reading:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended

Comment: We not using audio tag in our case audio element will not. E available in dom

Comment: Will any element be available in the DOM?

Comment: We create audio element as "new audio(URL)" in this audio element is not available in dom

Comment: Can you create the audio element as `var myAudioClip = document.createElement('audio'); document.body.appendChild('myAudioClip');` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addEventListener` and listen to the `ended` event just like when the `HTMLAudioElement` is in the DOM, e.g.

```
mySound = new Audio([URLString]);
mySound.addEventListener("ended", function(e) {
    // do whatever
})
```