# Two audio files play one by one

Tags: javascript, audio

By clicking `play` button two audio files should start playing one by one, but in my case they start playing at the same time. The question is how to make them play one by one, audio_1 then audio_2?

```
   let audio1 = new Audio('audio_1.mp3');
   audio1.play();  

   let audio2 = new Audio('audio_2.mp3');
   audio2.play();
```

Comment: Only play the second file `onended` of the first? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onended.asp

Comment: Check the answers in this question, maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069988/how-can-i-create-a-promise-for-the-end-of-playing-sound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a event listener to it:

```html
let audio1 = new Audio('audio_1.mp3');
let audio2 = new Audio('audio_2.mp3');

audio1.addEventListener('ended' => audio2.play());

audio1.play();
```

Comment: Hi @Valter, thank you for your response, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry about that @JohnPix, just need fix the event name from 'onended' to 'ended' and should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution with javascript `onended`.

```
let button = document.querySelector('button');
let audio = new Audio('audio_1.mp3');

function playAudio(){
audio.play();
audio.onended = function() {
    audio.src='audio_2.mp3'
    audio.play();
};
}

button.addEventListener(
'click', 
playAudio
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use promise.

```
function play(url) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {   // return a promise
     var audio = new Audio();                     // create audio wo/ src
     audio.preload = "auto";                      // intend to play through
     audio.autoplay = true;                       // autoplay when loaded
     audio.onerror = reject;                      // on error, reject
     audio.onended = resolve;                     // when done, resolve

     audio.src = path + url + suffix; // just for example
 });
}
```

Ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30070516/4811421) stackoverflow answer
Whenever you want to wait for some action and on it you want to do action on completion of previous one, use [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)